# Wifi ap bridge WLAN network with WAN network

Tags: switch, router, wireless, bridge

Googling "WLAN Bridge" mostly gives results about WDS bridge (wifi device to wifi device communication)

What i want to do is basically bridge the router's WLAN and WAN interface (disabling NAT, router's DHCP etc) so that once the wireless client successfully authenticates to the AP (wireless router), it gets an IP address not from the AP, but from a DHCP server further up the road (on the AP's WAN interface) and gets places inside a subnet defined by a router further up on the WAN interface.

Basically i want the AP to act only as a switch with additional wifi authentication (WPA2-PSK or WPA2-RADIUS).

Is such thing possible? How is this option usually called (so that i know what to look for in routers' specs when choosing the right one)

Additionaly, do you know if Ubiquiti APs support this mode?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WLAN-Ethernet bridge is called a wireless access point (WAP). Many WLAN routers can be switched to WAP mode.

If the WAN interface is provided as Ethernet this should be easy. If PPPoE is required the WLAN client would need to establish the session.